# Regular expression for not allowing some special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a regular expression for allowing alphanumeric values and special characters except the ones mentioned here '`', '^', '=', '"', '<', '>', '|' I am quite new to this and not really getting how to do it. I am trying something like below:

```
function dbaNameCheck(input, regex) 
{
  if (regex && input.value.length > 0)
   {
    if(regex.match(/dbaNameCheck/i) && input.value.match(/[0-9A-Za-z]|[\`\^\=\"\<\>\|]*/g))   
     {
         input.value = input.value.replace(/[\`\^\=\"\<\>\|]*/g, '');
         input.focus();
     }
   }
}
```

I am calling this function like this on keypress event:

```
onkeypress="dbaNameCheck(this,'dbaNameCheck');"
```

But it's not working as expected. The values in my textbox can be alphanumeric and any special character except the one mentioned above. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your function like this:

```
function dbaNameCheck(input) 
{
    var re = /[`\^="<>|]+/g;

    if (input.value.length > 0 && re.test(input.value))   
    {
        input.value = input.value.replace(re, '');
        input.focus();
    }
}
```

Then call it this way:

```
onkeyup="dbaNameCheck(this);"
```

onKeyup is the event you want to catch, instead of onKeypress.

Comment: Hi shinkou, Thanks for your answer but it is not allowing me to enter more than one character in the textbox. Actually the solution given by jcomeau_ictx works except that it is unable to detect the first occurence of the prohibited characters. E.g: If i write "asd>" then what i want is that the text should get reformatted to "asd" but that's not happening. however if i try to enter a ">" after "asd>" then that is getting prevented.I want the same behaviour on the first occurence too.

Comment: @Debojyoti, I've checked that it works on Firefox and Chrome.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Actually Shinkou, you are right. I forgot to use the onkeyup, also i believe you made some modifications to the regular expression. However, I owe you a treat, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Debojyoti, I was testing the sample code I gave you and noticed it didn't work, so I edited. (^^;

Answer (score 1):

`` /[^`^="<>|]/ `` should match everything except for those characters. the first ^ means "anything but the following characters".

---

but if you're going to replace those with the empty string, you probably *don't* want the `^` first.

```
'|||abc<==<<<'.replace(/[<>|]/g, '')
```

gives "abc==="

Comment: Thanks for adding the little comment about ^, +1 for teaching me something today.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer jcomeau_ictx. However, I actually tried that as shown below:

Answer (score 0):

FYI, here is another (old-school) way to achieve what you wanted to do, without using regex.  However, if can't deal with copy-and-paste.

First declare your function like

```
function killKeys(e)
{
    switch(e.charCode)
    {
    case 60: // "<"
    case 61: // "="
    case 62: // ">"
    case 94: // "^"
    case 96: // "`"
        return false;
        break;
    default:
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then call it like this

```
onkeypress="return killKeys(event);
```

Comment: though i prefer doing it with Regular expressions still i must thank you for sharing this alternative solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
        if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122) && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 96) && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) || charCode == 110 || charCode == 190)
            return false;
        return true;
    }    
</script>

<asp:TextBox  ID="txtCompany" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Could you add some text explaining the answer in addition to the code?